# Membership expired: now what for push notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am an Apple Developer but my program membership has expired.

My app that I was testing locally used push notifications so I signed up for an iOS push notification certificate via the membership center. After my program membership expired, when a user launches the app locally, the `NSLog` echoes out a `0` for the device token instead of a unique 64 character string. Do I have to pay for a new Program Membership from Apple to renew my iOS push notification certificates? Because when I log onto member center now, all it shows is a message saying to renew it.

Can someone post an official link or something for verification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to renew your account.

The [Supported Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1) page says Push Notifications for iOS require "an Apple ID associated with an Apple Developer Program membership".

Also, [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW1) says you need to be a team agent/admin to revoke your certificates. Obviously you need to be part of a team to have a team agent/admin.

You can also [call Developer Relations and ask](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/), but it should be somewhat intuitive that you don't get lifetime push notifications for buying 1 year of membership.

Comment: this is why i've missed you

Comment: I've missed you too. 